# Retore Realm Database auto Update

Tags: android, realm

I used [Restore realm database](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/example-class-to-export-import-a-realm-database-on-android-c429ade2b4ed#.8lwsves79) method to backup and restore database. everything was working fine but then i noticed that on clicking restore database it restores the database but updates it in next launch or on restart of app. Is there any way we can use the restored Realm database without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close all open Realm instances, then overwrite the Realm file, then re-open the instance, and requery your RealmResults.

Technically, [getGlobalInstanceCount](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#getGlobalInstanceCount-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-) must return `0` before you can reliably copy the Realm over the other one.

---

```
public static int getGlobalInstanceCount(RealmConfiguration configuration) {
    final AtomicInteger globalCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    RealmCache.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(configuration, new RealmCache.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(int count) {
            globalCount.set(count);
        }
    });
    return globalCount.get();
}
```

Comment: can you please give me full getGlobalInstancecount code